# FastAPI StreamingResponse media_type="application/pdf"

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to return a `pdf` file as

```
return StreamingResponse(generator, headers={"Content-Disposition": filename}, media_type="application/pdf")
```

Also, I raise an error if the file is not found

```
raise HTTPException(HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, "File not found")
```

The problem is that `redoc` shows

```
RESPONSE SCHEMA: application/json
```

I need the `response schema` to be `application/pdf` when successful, and `application/json` when `error` occurs.

I tried using `response_class` and `responses` in the decorator `@router.get()`, but neither of them worked :(

Answer (score 1):

for response a content-type application/json when you've exceptions you must return `Response` object (imported from: from starlette.responses import Response).

So, if exception raises, you must return like this:

```
try:
    ...
    return StreamingResponse(...)
except Exception as error:
    return Response(content={...}, status_code = ..., media_type='application/json)
```

But I saw that you execute raise method, I think you need an interceptor of exceptions on your main.py:

```
@app.exception_handler(AppException)
async def validation_exception_handler(
        request: Request,
        exc: AppException
):
"""

:param request:
:param exc:
:return:
"""
error = exc.detail
print("Error ->", error)  # this print is show in console stdout

return JSONResponse(
    status_code=exc.status_code,
    content={'detail': error}
)
```